# USB mount - Linux

Tags: usb

I have two questions:

1) How to mount the USB flash drive to make it appear on the "On this computer" section of Debian. I formatted the USB and, since then, I was not able to visualize it anymore.
2) How to boot a Windows image on a USB flash drive. I have already tried WoeUSB, but it seems it is not available on Debian.

I hope they are not bad questions to ask.

Comment: Including two questions in one makes for a vague question. Better to be specific... [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can build [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) from source.

Comment: Does it work on Debian? I lack on some to make it easier on Debian.

Comment: Info in the **Install WoeUSB's Build Dependencies** and **Build & Install WoeUSB** subsections of the **Build from Source** section of the **Installation** part of the `README.md` file displayed at the [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) site notes `# For Debian-based distributions`, so I would guess, "Yes," since Debian is "Debian-based." Please consult the site for detailed installation info.